# Laravel 3 - What's the best way to query start and end dates that are the same day

Tags: php, date, laravel

I have a web app written in Laravel 3. In this application one of the models is "Activities". These activities have both a start date and end date field. I was wondering what the best way is to query all Activities that start AND end the same day?

-- **Update** --

I'm using mySQL and the field types are both Timestamp...

**What I have currently**:

```
...

$activitySchedule = ActivitySchedule::with(array('location'))->where(function($query) {         

    // Query activities that start and end today
    $yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today')) . ' 00:00:00';
    $tomorrow = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today')) . ' 23:59:59';
    $query->where('starts', '>', $yesterday);
    $query->where('ends', '<', $tomorrow);
});

...
```

I think this works properly but I'm wondering if there is a more precise method?

Comment: So, all activities where start date equals end date?

Comment: Are you using eloquent (is the model extending it?)?

Comment: please edit you question and add more information.. using eloquent? what the date field type.. what have you tried? which database?

Comment: @amirbar - I've updated my question. Sorry for not being clear enough. I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Carbon package which would allow you to get `startOftheDay` and `endoftheday` like this:

```
$StartofDay = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$EndofDay = Carbon::now()->endOfDay();
```

Once you have this in place, query your model with a where condition involving a condition to check using `StartofDay` and `EndofDay` values along with `created_at` column.

Find carbon package here : https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Hope it helps.!!